# Canvasjs: different settings according to screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvasjs

I'm using [CanvasJs](http://canvasjs.com/) for a bar chart, but I would like to have different settings according to screen size.

For example, I would like to hide labels completely on the axisY for screens < 480px. How can this be done?

It seems that media queries and css can't be used to customize the charts.

Here's an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
            title: {
                text: "Understanding Labels"
            },
            axisY: {
                labelFontSize: 20
            },
            axisX: {
                labelAngle: -30
            },
            data: [
            {
                type: "column",
                dataPoints: [
                { y: 10, label: "Apples" },
                { y: 15, label: "Mangos" },
                { y: 25, label: "Oranges" },
                { y: 30, label: "Grapes" },
                { y: 28, label: "Bananas" }
                ]
            }
            ]
        });

    chart.render();
    }
</script>
```

I experimented with something like this which obviously doesn't work:

```
axisY: {
  labelFormatter: function(e) {
    if ($(window).width() < 480) {
      return "";
    },
  },
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a function for labelFormatter outside of axisY object.

```
axisY: {
    labelFormatter: axisYLabels,
},
```

You can modify the labels of axisY here based on width of the window.

```
function axisYLabels(e) {
    if ($(window).width() < 480) {
       return "";
    } else {
        return e.value;
    }
}
```

You can see a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amp7nms1/) here.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. But how do I display initial label value when the screen width is more than 480px? Right now the function returns `e.value` which is the index number and not the label text. See example here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/amp7nms1/1/)